# How is current produced by one rotating charged sphere?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current

I was doing this problem today:

*This question came in the Dhaka University admission exam 20-21*

Q) A sphere with charge $q$ is rotating by a non-conducting string at an angular speed $\omega$. What is the amount of current produced by the charged sphere?

(A) $\omega q$

(B) $2\pi\omega q$

(C) $\frac{q}{\omega}$

(D) $\frac{q\omega}{2\pi}$

**Third-party question bank's attempt:**

$$I=\frac{q}{T}=\frac{q}{\frac{2\pi}{\omega}}=\frac{q\omega}{2\pi}$$

So, (D).

**My comments:**

I have some problems with this question. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current),

> An electric current is a stream of charged particles, such as
> electrons or ions, moving through an electrical conductor or space.

There is no such **stream** of charged particles in the setup of the question. Only **one** charged sphere is moving/rotating. How will only **one** charged sphere produce current?

[Moreover, according to Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current#Conduction_mechanisms_in_various_media)

> For a steady flow of charge through a surface, the current I (in
> amperes) can be calculated with the following equation:
>
> $$I=\frac{Q}{t}$$
>
> , where Q is the electric charge transferred through the surface over
> a time t.

In the setup of the question, there is no **steady flow of charge through a surface**. Only one charged sphere is moving/rotating. So, how can $I=\frac{Q}{t}$ be applicable here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current can be defined as amount of charge passing through an area per unit time. One thing that is not clear in the given question is whether the sphere is conductive (all charge is at the surface of the sphere) or insulator (the charge is somewhat distributed over the entire sphere).

The solution I suggest below works for both a conductor sphere and an insulator sphere in which the charge is homogenously distributed with a volume charge density $\rho$.

Assume that in a given time $dt$ the sphere is rotated an angle $d\theta$. The amount of charge $dQ$ that passes through the cross section (half disk) of the sphere is the volume of the [spherical wedge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_wedge) times the volume charge density

$$dQ=\rho \frac{2}{3}R^3d\theta.$$

The volume charge density $\rho$ can be calculated as

$$\rho= \frac{q}{\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3}$$

therefore

$$dQ=\frac{qd\theta}{2\pi}.$$

Because current (as stated above) defined as $I=dQ/dt$, we have

$$I=\frac{dQ}{dt}=\frac{q}{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{q\omega}{2\pi}.$$

[image: https://thenounproject.com/icon/spherical-wedge-405682/]

Answer (score 1):

The "charged particles" are electrons or ions on the sphere.  "through a surface" does not seem to be in the Wiki definition.

Comment: The problem is not stated clearly. What does "rotated" mean.  Is  this a sphere dangling from a string and  rotating about its axis,  or is it sphere being whirled at the end of a string? The later case gives an effective current loop of radius the length of the string.